# How to apply a php bug patch

Tags: php, patch

I want to uptake fix for this PHP Bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52043

I am not sure on how can I install this patch. Conceptually I understand I need to follow following steps:

- get php code & GD module code
- apply code fix or patch to code
- compile
- reinstall using compiled files

But I have never done these steps before, so I am not sure about commands for any of the above steps.

Can someone elaborate on this process. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit, and this bug is blocking me from using GD module with php.

Also is there a tool or script to do the complete patching process in an automated way?

Answer (score -1):

you have to copy/paste the patch code from bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48886 in simple text file lets say php.patch then unpack php tarball and in the same directory issue the command above. Notice that that patch works well only for php version 5.3 with any other php version you can meet some problems

This is  the command you have to use .

```
patch -p1 < /path/to/patch/file
```

credit goes here:[www.webhostingtalk.com](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1008902)

Comment: This is not a sufficient explanation. This merely explains how to apply *a* patch and does nothing on how to get PHP's source, how to apply the patch in this case, or how to rebuild and repackage PHP - all of which would be required to do this properly.